# How to get all commits from all branches via bitbucket REST api 1.0?

Tags: rest, bitbucket

I want to get all commit data from all branches via Bitbucket REST api 1.0 like this :

```
curl -u $id:$password http://$path/rest/api/1.0/projects/$project/repos/$slug/commits
```

All I get is all commit data from **a default branch** only, not all branches.

**What I want** is like this :

```
curl -u $id:$password http://$path/rest/api/1.0/projects/$project/repos/$slug/commits?branches=all
```

Of course, it doesn't work. :/

I've already read the official document but I cannot find a clue.
https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/6.10.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idp205

I guess, getting all branch list, and then searching all commits at each branch can be possible. It seems annoying because I have 200 projects and almost 4,000 repositories.

I need your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out there is currently **no single endpoint** to return all the commits associated with all branches.

There was a suggestion few years ago but it was rejected by the developers.
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-5363

**The only way** to get all commits across all branches is :

1. Make an api call for all the /branches
2. For each branch make an api call for its /commits?until=
3. Remove duplicate commits, then insert the branch commits by timestamp.

Comment: What logic would you apply to remove duplicate commits? I have seen instances where a single commit hash appears across anywhere from 1-5 branches (depending on how it was merged across from develop to feature to release/master branches). Would you attribute them to a master/release branch, or rather the child branch (develop, feature branches)?